# Remove Multiple Categories from Product In HYbris Using Impex

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

How multiple categories can be removed and added to a product using impex in HYbris
in a single row
Something like:

```
REMOVE CategoryProductRelation;target[unique=true](code,$catalogVersion);source[unique=true](code,$catalogVersion)

;xyz;cat1,cat2,cat3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also try :

```
$ProductCatalogVersion=catalogVersion(catalog(id[default='$catalogID']),version[default='$catalogVersionID_STAGED'])[unique=true,default='$catalogID:$catalogVersionID_STAGED']
$CategoryCatalogVersion=catalogVersion(catalog(id[default='$catalogID']),version[default='$catalogVersionID_STAGED'])[unique=true,default='$catalogID:$catalogVersionID_STAGED']

$superCategories=supercategories(code,$CategoryCatalogVersion)


INSERT_UPDATE Product;$ProductCatalogVersion;code[unique=true];$superCategories[mode = remove]
;;xyz;cat1,cat2,cat3
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Remove it 1 line each.

```
 REMOVE CategoryProductRelation;target(code,$catalogVersion)[unique=true];source(code,$catalogVersion)[unique=true]

 ;xyz;cat1
 ;xyz;cat2
 ;xyz;cat3
```